# Python automation click in windows under linux

Tags: python, linux

I would like to see what is the best library to use in order to do some automations under linux x environment.

I have an application that is running in a window (I use Ubuntu but I need to make sure it would work under another distribution). In this window that can be anywhere in my environment, I want to be able to execute some click at specific x,y coordinates then monitor also some squares to see if I have an image coming and when it does, execute some other clicks at different places. This would allow me to automate some applications I have.

Could you please tell me how to best do that with python 2 or 3?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use pyautogui module. The docs are here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. Use pyautogui.click().

Comment: Thanks for the comment. And can you tell me how I can select into a window that can be placed somewhere each time?

Comment: Sorry, I am not on the hang of what you are asking

Comment: do you mean, the command of how to move your mouse to open nd close applications? If so, then use pyautogui.moveTo(xcor, ycor)

Comment: in fact if I launch my python software but I have moved the window of the application, then all x,y have changed. How do I make them relative to the window and not the whole screen.

Comment: Help yourself with pyautogui.findOnScreen(), and in brackets enter a name of an image of the top menubar of python window (It is always the same - file, edit...). Then put your mouse a few pixels above to drag the mouse on the python gui toolbar. It is the best solution which I can think of.